# Dynacache - Caching everything

Tags: caching, websphere, websphere-liberty, distributed-caching

I have taken over an application that serves around 180 TPS. The responses are always SOAP XML responses with a size of around 24000 bytes. We have been told that we have a dynacache and i can see that we have a cachespec.xml. But I am unable to understand how many entries it holds currently and its max limit.

1. How can i check this? I have tried  `DynamicCacheAccessor.getDistributedMap().size()` but this always returns 0.
2. We have a lot of data inconsistencies because of Java hashmap caching layers internally. What are your thoughts on increasing dynacache and eliminate the internal caching ? How much server memory might this consume ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The DynamicCacheAccessor accesses the default servlet cache instance, baseCache.   If size() always returns zero then your cachespec.xml is configured to use a different cache instance.

Look for a directive in the cachespec.xml:
`<cache-instance name="cache_instance_name"></cache-instance>` to determine what cache instance you are using.

Also install the Cache Monitor from the installableApps directory.  See 
[Monitoring](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tdyn_servletmonitor.html) and
[CacheMonitor](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/cdyn_cachemonitor.html). The Cache Monitor is an invaluable tool when developing/maintaining an app using servlet caching.

Using liberty, install the [webCacheMonitor-1.0](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/features-com.ibm.websphere.appserver.webCacheMonitor-1.0) feature.